# Is there a way to customize email notifications I receive from contact form submissions?

Tags: javascript, forms, email, weebly

Using Weebly: when a user submits a contact form entry, I receive a notification email with their information. The problem is that the information I receive only includes what the user typed into input fields, radio boxes, dropdowns, etc. It does not include any custom headings, paragraph text, or HTML I added within the form.

Is there a way to force Weebly to include that custom information in my email notifications?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to get paragraph text, HTML or other content in the email.

The only thing that will appear in the Email is:

- FIELD TITLES
- FIELD INPUT VALUES

So, if you wanted to add text to the email it would have to be part of a **field title**.

You are always welcome to [Suggest an idea here](https://community.weebly.com/t5/Vote-on-Features/idb-p/IdeaExchange/label-name/community%20feature%20request)